# Is it possible to convert virtual non-static to static method without doing major refactoring?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following:

```
class RecordCommon {
public:
   virtual const char* GetShortName(void) const = 0;
   ...
   virtual void DoSomeWork(void);
};

class RecordCLDT : public RecordCommon {
   virtual const char* GetShortName(void) const { return "CLDT"; }
};

void RecordCommon::DoSomeWork(void) {
   ...
   log(GetShortName());
   ...
}
```

What I want to have is static method like RecordCLDT::GetShortName(void) that would return"CLDT" without doing major refactoring of the project. Maybe this could be done by some macro or smart template technique?

I need to have RecordCommon::DoSomeWork(void) calling the correct GetShortName() function which it wouldn't if I just replace virtual GetShortName() with static one.

Re-writing every single child class of RecordCommon would be very time-consuming especially since virtual GetShortName() is used in the code.

Comment: This is what shell/perl/python scripts are for. Unfortunately, there is no magic button, somewhere in C++, that only needs to be located, and pushed,  in order to do everything. Sometimes you have to do all the work yourself. Alternative: Step 1: enable the compiler flag that requires all overrides to be explicitly marked `override`, else compilation failure. Step 2: fix all compilation failures. Step 3: replace the non-static function with the static one. Step 4: fix all compilation failures.

Comment: *Why* do you want to make a static `RecordCLDT::GetShortName`? You *are* using `this`, to distinguish which implementation is called.

Comment: "*I need to have `RecordCommon::DoSomeWork(void)` calling the correct `GetShortName()` function*" Call it *on what*? Static functions aren't given an object to work on, and it is the object which determines what "the correct function" even is.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  What problems did you encounter when you tried?  (I'm not sure what you consider "major refactoring".  Unless you have many, many classes involved, it isn't what I'd consider "major.")

Comment: "major refactoring" because there are 80+ classes already

Answer (score 2):

No, and you shouldn't want to. Anything you would do yourself would end up behaving like `virtual` anyway.

Just because you aren't accessing any of the data members of `RecordCLDT`, it doesn't mean you can make it static, you still need it to be an `override` of the base class member to call the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

`virtual` functions work because there is information hidden in the object that tells the system what object the pointer/reference *really* points to. This is what allows the correct function to be called for a given object.

If you want to remove `virtual` functions, you must *replace* this functionality. That is, instead of having hidden data in the object that says which kind of object it is, you must have *explicit* data in the object, which different functions will look at to tell which type it really is and therefore how to behave.

This is not a trivial thing to do, and how best to do it depends on a variety of factors. You can't just make a `static` member, rip out some `virtual`s, and expect everything to still work. The data that says what type the object is still has to be there and must be accessible from the base class. If you remove the implicit data, you must add explicit data.